# Google Map autocomplete Location API for bangalore

Tags: android

I need suggestion that how to do autocomplete location API for FROM address and TO address for bangalore in android,is that api will available in google or else we have to prepare web service.Please try to suggest me

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you didn't need to prepare any web-service,google auto-complete api provide the list of  places itself.

Comment: be specific on your requirement . explain more .

Comment: see this link -https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

Answer (score 0):

you can use google auto complete fragment powered by google itself [try this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment)